# AC capacitor testing with multimeter

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, cooling

When running through my check list to start the AC for the spring/summer I noticed the outdoor fan was not running, hence no cooling.  I'm using a basic digital multimeter to test a capacitor with the help of Youtube.  In the video, the meter set at 2000K ohm instantly displays a reading and jumps back to zero.  On my capacitor, the meter displays a multitude of readings and never goes to zero, for both the fan and herm terminals.  Is this an indication of a bad capacitor?

Comment: I don't know about the video but generally you test capacitors by comparing the rated microfarads with the measured microfarads as measured by your multimeter in the appropriate mode.  A link to the video might also be helpful.

Comment: I have a basic meter, without a microfarad mode.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBoOx8YzD_s

Comment: I watched the video and I don't think that's an accurate way of testing capacitors. To be honest though if the motor shaft rotates and there's no sign of damage to the motor or wiring I would throw in a new capacitor. A fan motor capacitor in the 3-7μF range tops out around 5-10 dollars. Good luck.

Comment: If all you have is a hammer... testing a cap with a DVOM is like that.  If you have any electronics kit, I'd look into RC circuits. See if the cap behaves as expected.

Comment: You **cannot** measure capacitance solely with a volt-ohm-ammeter.   You could, for example, put the cap on a bench, charge it up to some small voltage w/ a battery , and then do a DC voltage test to see if the cap is holding voltage, **and** measure current to verify there's zero current after it charges up.

Comment: If you have a meter with a cap setting, as in this video,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plWSIrkxZRE,  then go for it

Comment: Did you remove the capacitor from the circuit before testing it?

Comment: Use the ohm setting with the cap disconnected put the leads on the cap. You are looking for a increase in resistance as the cap charges, reverse the leads and try the other direction. If there is a bleed resistor it will need to be removed or you will just read the value of the resistor. If you don't see the cap charging it is bad. Many starting caps are 20-100uf and it is common for them to go bad. If you can see any bulging on the case it needs to be replaced.

Comment: Ed, thanks, your info validates my initial idea.  The herm side gradually increases while the fan side continuously bounces from high to low.  This seems to explain why the condenser starts and the fan just sits.  While I'm not reading the capacity, I am reading resistance which should increase and not bounce around.  A 45 5 440 is $13 for a USA part online, should be here in a couple of days.